# Unable to get push notifications to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement push notifications in my application. I am using APNs Authentication Key. Every guide I found so far has either deprecated method or it's in Swift. I am interested in a guide like [this one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) but in Objective C.

What I have done so far, inside AppDelegate.m :

```
@import Firebase;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FIRApp configure];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (userInfo) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
    }

    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    return YES;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {



    // Perform different operations depending on the scenario
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        // Opening the app
        NSLog(@"Firebase opening app");


    }
    else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

        // Coming from background
        NSLog(@"Firebase background");

    }
    else {

        // Active
        NSLog(@"Firebase active");
    }

}
```

Unfortunately when I send a message from firebase I get nothing, no output in xcode Console and no notification. 
I would appreciate it if you can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not implement the firebase apn token neither you connect to the database. Why not just implement it like here [firebase example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExample/AppDelegate.m#L64-L84).
Did you even setup the plist and the POD libs? In the code example above there is only deprecated code for the iOS part of version 8/9 - means u can ignore these code lines.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks mate

Comment: Your welcome. I implemented itself in my last project and it works 100%. BTW do not forget to upload a certificate in firebase (only for iOS, Android does not need it). I am still on Objective-C like you - love it! Greetz

Answer (score 0):

Please use this method:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
//Do something
}
```

instead of this:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
 //Do something
}
```

**Update:**

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FIRApp configure];

    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
      {
        #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                                                                                             | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                             | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        #endif
       }
    else
      {
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
      }
    return YES;
}




-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{

    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: Did you use `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method ?

Comment: No, where and how should I use this? Do you have any reference?

Comment: I have updated the answer, Have a look! and let me know if your problem is solved.

Comment: Hey thank you for your time. I used the code from the github and it worked perfectly. Cheers